# How to hide Bootstrap navbar drop-down menu when any link is clicked in an Angular app?

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3

On narrow screens, the Bootstrap navbar is presented as a panel of buttons that overlay the page content. There are many questions and answers addressing problems getting that panel to be hidden when it is clicked on - that is not the problem I am trying to solve.

This question is how to get that panel to be hidden when links in the main body of the page are clicked **and** when those links are produced by AngularJs templates. Is there a simple solution?

Here is the relevant content of the main page into which Angular inserts content:

```
<html lang="en" xmlns:ng="http://angularjs.org" id="ng-app" ng-app="eepApp"
        ng-controller="AppController">
<head>
...
</head>
<body>

<!-- Small screen menu -->
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top visible-xs" role="navigation">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse"
                    data-target="#navbar-collapse-id">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left pull-left">
                ...
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse-id">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                ...
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<!--  Bigger screen menu -->
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top hidden-xs" role="navigation">
    ...
</div>

<!--  Page content inserted by Angular here -->
<div id="partials" ng-view="partials"></div>

<script src="various JavaScript inculding Angular and jQuery"/>

<script>

// Hide navbar menu when item clicked
$(document).on('click', '.navbar-collapse.in', function(e) {
    if ($(e.target).is('a') || $(e.target).parent().is('a')) {
        $(this).collapse('hide');
    }
});

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you be more specific? Provide some code to demonstrate what you have.

Comment: @Skelly I've added a chopped down version of the main page. The question is how to get content that Angular inserts to cause the Bootstrap menu to close when any link in the content is clicked. The on("click") JavaScript already in the page only closes the menu when a link on the menu is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

I've gone for this approach where when the page changes the class that keeps the navbar menu open (called "in") is removed using jQuery:

```
$scope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function() {
    // Close navbar menu (if open) by removing the class that makes it visible
    $('#navbar-collapse-id').removeClass('in');
});
```

This is added to the overall app controller that also handles e.g. login and logout.